# Only partial message sent with SMTP

Tags: python, smtp

I have an SMTP setup where I am sending emails to an email address as well as a text to an email address like [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/email-to-sms/). Though the problem is the email receives the full message, which is "Phase monitor, system off" but the phone just receives "Phase monitor, system o". I've sent longer messages and it received them so I don't think it is a length issue. Any ideas why the text is different? Code below.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

emails = ["me@gmail.com", "my_number@tmomail.net"]

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login("username", "password")

for email in emails:    
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = 'me@work.com'
    msg['To'] = email
    msg['Subject'] = 'Chiller Alarm'
    body = "Phase monitor, system off"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
    server.sendmail("me@work.com", email, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Oddly enough, I just added 8 f's to "off" so it became "offffffff" and it sent with 6 f's. So it there's that?

Answer? When I added `\n` to the end of the message it sent correctly. I have no clue what is going on with this but at least it is working.

Comment: Does it expect `CR/LF` at the end?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't think so because it seems to only be a problem with the text and multiple f's. How would I check though? I also tried off with 4 f's and that sent "off" so it looks like it just wants to get rid of 2 f's. Edit: Adding `\n` to the end of the message fixed the issue. Though I still don't know why it is an issue.